# How to make a video align with image grid?

Tags: html, image, video, grid, alignment

I am trying to align a video file next to a grid of images in html. I can't seem to find the right combination of code to make it fit correctly and still be functional.

Here is the grid working correctly if I use an image as a place holder for the video:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="336" height="460"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is video&nbsp;1</p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image&nbsp;1</p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image&nbsp;2</p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image 3</p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image 4</p>
```

Here is my attempt at adding the video, but it only displays as an image or video icon:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><video src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline_compress2.mp4" width="271" height="600">
</video></p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image&nbsp;1</p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image&nbsp;2</p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image 3</p>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="middle-img" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="158" height="216"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">This is image 4</p>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
<div><video src="blah.mp4" width="271" height="600"></video></div>
<div>[video  width="271" height="600" src="blah.mp4"[/video]</div>
```

neither seem to do it, I'm thinking I'm forgetting some tags.

Comment: Wat do you mean exactly? [TEST](https://jsfiddle.net/3w1cp9fn/) can you point out what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bootstrap grids.

You will have to include the bootstrap.css file in the head tag. Then you can use code like this to arrange video and text/images in the same page.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">col-8</div>
  <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting a specific height and width for the video embed, so it won't be responsive.  Your theme appears to be using BoldGrid as well, so the Bootstrap 3 grid is already available for you.  Using the editor I put a video in one column, then added three columns next to it with an image and text below.  Also take note that the last attempt you had with above where you used the video shortcode was close, but was actually missing the closing bracket (]) on the shortcode!

This is the markup result that you can try:

```
    <div class="boldgrid-section">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 align-column-center">

    [video mp4="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/blurry-night.mp4"][/video]
    <p class="" style="text-align: center;">This is Video 1</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 align-column-center">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-17892 middle-img" src="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/5971aba9a4a52-300x169.jpeg" alt="" width="158" height="216"></p>

    <div>
    <p class="" style="text-align: center;">This is image&nbsp;1</p>

    </div>
    <div>
    <p class="mod-reset">&nbsp;</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 align-column-center">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-17892 middle-img" src="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/5971aba9a4a52-300x169.jpeg" alt="" width="158" height="216"></p>
    <p class="" style="text-align: center;">This is image 2</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 align-column-center">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-17892 middle-img" src="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/5971aba9a4a52-300x169.jpeg" alt="" width="158" height="216"></p>
    <p class="" style="text-align: center;">This is image 3</p>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The video was not responsive, so viewing the rendered shortcode on the front end, you can see what WordPress translates the video shortcode into markup wise for the player.

To make the video responsive, you can go into the customizer > advanced > css & js editor to add custom CSS and JS to the site.  This was the CSS I used:

```
    .wp-video, video.wp-video-shortcode, .mejs-container, .mejs-overlay.load {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    .mejs-container {
        padding-top: 56.25%;
    }
    .wp-video, video.wp-video-shortcode {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
    video.wp-video-shortcode {
        position: relative;
    }
    .mejs-mediaelement {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .mejs-controls {
        display: none;
    }
    .mejs-overlay-play {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
```

This is basically getting the player to span 100% of it's area it's inside of - in our case that's one of the col-md-3 (ie we had 4 columns out of a possible 12 columns in bootstrap).

To maintain the aspect ratio that video had, you can open up the JS editor, and add this code:

```
    $( function() {
        $( '.mejs-overlay-loading' ).closest( '.mejs-overlay' ).addClass( 'load' );

        var $video = $( 'div.video video' );
        var vidWidth = $video.attr( 'width' );
        var vidHeight = $video.attr( 'height' );

        $( window ).resize( function() {
            var targetWidth = $( this ).width();
            $( 'div.video, div.video .mejs-container' ).css( 'height', Math.ceil(vidHeight * ( targetWidth / vidWidth ) ) );
        }).resize();
    });
```